# How to re-render a parent from a children component with hook?

Tags: reactjs

I would like to force my parent to re-render the page when I click on a button from a child component.
(I don't use redux because I don't have the time to learn it in my project, so I use localStorage. Unfortunately React don't see when a change is operated on local Storage, so he don't re-render. It's why I would like to force it to re-render my page (to have the right content).)

I tried to use hook with the function useState to do it but it's not working and I don't know why...
(Nothing change in my page)

This is my parent page: (just the code important)

```
const[reload, setReload] = useState(false);
...
else if (user) { contents = [<Message_UserIdentified user={user} callBack={setReload}/>, contentform]; }
```

This is my child component:

```
const Message_UserIdentified = (props) => {
    let user = props.user;
    return (
        <Alert color="primary" className="alert alert-dismissible alert-info">
            <h4>Welcome {!user ? "" : user.firstname} {!user ? "" : user.lastname}</h4>
            If you are not {!user  ? "" : user.firstname} click <a onClick={() => {localStorage.removeItem('idUser'); props.callBack(true);}}>here.</a>
        </Alert>
    );
}
```

Why my parent page don't want re-render ? 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Avoid using localStorage to drive changes in your app. Make your React state the 'source of truth', and when your state changes, save them to localStorage. You'll find `useEffect` useful for saving to localStorage.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I have created a proof of concept of what you are trying to achieve and it works:

https://codesandbox.io/s/weathered-smoke-ojr5j

probably there's something else in your code that we can't see that's preventing the component to re render

Answer (score 1):

Your child component can have a prop which directly pass `setReload` to it.

However one common usage is that, `setReload` can be associated with an event, ex. `onReload`. You can pass a prop `onReload` to the child instead.

```
  <Child onReload={() => { setReload() }} />
```

Inside `onReload` implementation, you can call `setReload`.

Answer (score 0):

The `reload` state variable in your parent component is strictly local to it; the child can't see it.

I've been using React Hooks for about 2 months now.  The learning curve, at times, has been steep but I'm now getting really proficient at it.

A companion technology to Hooks called Context API is perfect for your needs.  It's what you should be using rather than local storage because both components can access it.  Your child component would set the equivalent of `reload` in the Context to `true` and your parent would have a `useEffect` function that would have `reload` as a dependency.  Thus, when `reload` is changed from `false` to `true`, the `useEffect` function in the parent would be fired and run the code you desire.

Early on, I very much benefitted from this video series: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6RhOzQciVwI&t=46s  Watch the first few videos and you should quickly understand how to implement the Context API in your functional React components.